# Implementing PageViewController in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller

I can't seem to get a simple answer to this anywhere. I have a Page View Controller and similar lay-outs for all of the other view-controllers.

This is working without problems if I have one view-controller per view, but it seems very inefficient given that all the lay-outs are the same.

I've seen tutorials like this, but not for Swift. Is it possible to use a single view controller for all the pages and just switch out the text or images? If so, can you please explain how this is done?

Comment: What do you feel is inefficient about it? You'll only be creating 3 at the most.

Comment: It's pretty much just a title and body text on each view controller. It just feels a little weird to create the exact same thing for three of them without trying to see how I can reduce the redundancy?

Comment: You only have to create one and reuse it.

Comment: That's the question. I'm a bit unclear as to how to do that.

Comment: Have you looked at https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/PageViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011313-CH4-SW3 ?

Comment: Reading through it right now. I'm just confused as to how to implement the data source protocol... I'm new at this.

Comment: I gathered you are new, don't worry about that. So you're question is really, do you really need to declare more than one type of view controller? No. You declare one type if all the "pages" are the same, but you create separate instances of them.

Comment: Right, so to give you an idea of what I have, I've got one view controller class for all the pages. All I have to do now is to somehow dynamically create the "pages" on an as-needed basis in the pageviewcontroller. Is that right? If so, are there any good examples of this in Swift?

Comment: Go to Xcode, create a new project and chose the Page Based Application template. It's a ready made example of using a single page controller and adding content.

Comment: Wow, oops! Thanks for that.

Comment: You're welcome. It should give you and idea of how to implement the pattern. Give it a try and if you can't manage to do it, at least you'll be able to ask a more specific question about what exactly is causing you problems.

Comment: Appreciate that, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is make each page link to the same viewController and then dynamically change the content on each page based on the page number associated with it. You could easily have some elements that were hidden or diabled on certain views.